# Modular code for CLI and library in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm developing an application which is called by **2 differents mecanisms**:

1. In CLI, via a `main.py` file (standalone Python application): `python main.py --args ...`
2. From other Python application (as a library?)

I would like to have a "modular" code, meaning by that a way to change some behavior.
i.e. My main class have a method `generate_output()` which print a string in stdout (fake example).

```py
class ipdisco:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 'a string'
    def generate_output(self):
        print(self.test)
```

How can I add some other different output, for example, an output in csv, output in json, output in png, etc ...
My application is designed like this

```
main.py
ipdisco/
  __init__.py
  ipdisco.py
```

I want to add other output method by 'loading plugins'. But I don't know how to do it.
Right now, I have multiple function in my `main.py` script which take the class in argument and parse it.

`main.py`:

```py
import ipdisco
def generate_pprint(var):
    print(f"Here is a beautiful string : {var}")

def main(argv):
    ipdisco_obj = ipdisco.ipdisco()
    generate_pprint(ipdisco_obj.test)
    # Here is a beautiful string : a string
    ipdisco_obj.generate_output()
    # a string
```

But I pretty sure this is not a best practice for changing/adding other behavior in a library.
I previously seen some library using other prettier method, like using class inheritance, `__import__`, or other things.

Maybe something like that (just an example) :

```
class ipdisco:
    def __init__(self):
        self.test = 'a string'
    def generate_output(self, function=base_output):
        function(self.test)
    def base_output(self, arg):
        print(arg)

in main.py:
import ipdisco
def custom_pprint(var):
    print(f"Here is a beautiful string : {var}")
def custom2_pprint(var):
    print(f"Here is another beautiful string : {var}")

def main(argv):
    ipdisco_obj = ipdisco.ipdisco()
    ipdisco_obj.generate_output()
    # a string
    ipdisco_obj.generate_output(function = custom_pprint)
    # Here is a beautiful string : a string
    ipdisco_obj.generate_output(function = custom2_pprint)
    # Here is another beautiful string : a string
```

Comment: Your question is really not clear. Why not just allow access to those functions? Please post a [mre] actually demonstrating the problem

Comment: @Tomerikoo I've edited my question, hope it's clearier. What do you mean by 'allow access to those functions'